# How can I catch a bound data updated event?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am writing an app for windows 8 and I have a UI class called `GroupedItemsPage` which inherits from `LayoutAwarePage` that contains the data :

```
 this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
```

Each item in sampleDataGroups is binded to a tile in the UI and sampleDataGroups is a class which inherits from BindableBase and each property is set using

```
set{this.SetProperty(ref this._property, value); }
```

What I would like to do is to be able to catch a general event in my UI class `GroupedItemsPage` each time a property in sampleDataGroups is changed (so that I can rewrite sampleDataGroups to a file). I've done some research and I've only really found how to do get the notify event caught for sampleDataGroups, but not if I want sampleDataGroups to notify `GroupedItemsPage`?

Comment: you can use `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: @Sushil can you please elaborate? I looked into the PropertyChanged event but it seems to have to be implemented in my sampleDataGroups class rather than the GroupedItemsPage.

Comment: like mentioned by Filip below, its best practice to save the file in view model class. you can check `OnPropertyChanged' method in BindableBase class in common folder, you can override it in sampleDataGroups - put code here to save contents to file, and call base class impl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page should not be writing data to a file. It's more of a duty of the view model or model rather. If you really have to though then you will need to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event declared by the type of your `sampleDataGroups` variable and handle the event in your page object.